# Exchange a jwt for an access token returns invalid_grant error

Tags: .net, jwt, docusignapi

I'm trying to implement Service Integration Authentication - Admin Consent for my application. Here's how I created the jwt:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region Test

        string integratorKey = "integratorKey ";
        string userId = "userId ";
        string serverAddress = "serverAddress";
        string scope = "signature";
        string key = @"C:\Users\Tester\Desktop\privatekey.txt";

        // JWT Header
        // The header specfies the token type and the signature algorithm
        var jwtHeader = new JwtHeader
        {
            { "typ ", "JWT "},
            { "alg", "RS256"},
        };

        // JWT Body
        // The body specfies the account and user id granting consen
        var jwtPayload = new JwtPayload
        {
           { "iss ", integratorKey},
           { "sub", userId},
           { "iat", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()},
           { "exp", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1).ToUnixTimeSeconds()},
           { "aud", serverAddress},
           { "scope", scope}
        };

        // JWT Signature
        // The body contains the result of signing the base64url-encoded header and body
        string pemKey = File.ReadAllText(key);
        var rsa = CreateRSAKeyFromPem(pemKey);
        RsaSecurityKey rsaKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);

        var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(jwtHeader, jwtPayload);
        jwtSecurityToken.SigningKey = rsaKey;

        // Token to String so you can use it in your client
        var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var tokenString = jwtHandler.WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);
        #endregion
    }

    public static RSA CreateRSAKeyFromPem(string key)
    {
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(key);
        PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(reader);

        object result = pemReader.ReadObject();

        if (result is AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)
        {
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)result;
            return DotNetUtilities.ToRSA((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.Private);
        }
        else if (result is RsaKeyParameters)
        {
            RsaKeyParameters keyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)result;
            return DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(keyParameters);
        }

        throw new Exception("Unepxected PEM type");
    }
}
```

I have verified the token generated by this code on jwt.io and all looks good. However when I tried to exchange a generated jwt for an access code using Postman, I will always get "invalid_grant", here's how I made the request in postman:

```
POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
-Headers: Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

-Body: grant_type urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer assertion [Generated jwt]
```

I even tried putting

```
Headers: Authorization Basic b64encoded(integratorKey:secretKey)
```

as well but still no luck.

Could you please point out what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to figure out what were wrong myself and I can now receive the access token in Postman. 3 things that I have changed to make this work:

1. When I Authorize Application from Organization Portal, I have assigned the application to an incorrect Integrator Key so I need to change that to point to the correct one.
2. I found in the C# SDK the code to generate jwt so I used that to make sure the jwt created is accepted by DocuSign:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string integratorKey = "integratorKey ";
       string userId = "userId ";
       string serverAddress = "account-d.docusign.com";
       string scope = "signature impersonation";
       string privateKeyFilename = @"C:\Users\Tester\Desktop\privatekey.txt";

       JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

       SecurityTokenDescriptor descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
       {
           IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
           Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
       };

       descriptor.Subject = new ClaimsIdentity();
       descriptor.Subject.AddClaim(new Claim("scope", scope));
       descriptor.Subject.AddClaim(new Claim("aud", serverAddress));
       descriptor.Subject.AddClaim(new Claim("iss", integratorKey));

       if (userId != null)
       {
           descriptor.Subject.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", userId));
       }

       if (privateKeyFilename != null)
       {
           string pemKey = File.ReadAllText(privateKeyFilename);
           var rsa = CreateRSAKeyFromPem(pemKey);
           RsaSecurityKey rsaKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
           descriptor.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(rsaKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
       }

       var token = handler.CreateToken(descriptor);
       string jwtToken = handler.WriteToken(token);
   }

   public static RSA CreateRSAKeyFromPem(string key)
   {
       TextReader reader = new StringReader(key);
       PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(reader);

       object result = pemReader.ReadObject();

       if (result is AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)
       {
           AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)result;
           return DotNetUtilities.ToRSA((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keyPair.Private);
       }
       else if (result is RsaKeyParameters)
       {
           RsaKeyParameters keyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)result;
           return DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(keyParameters);
       }

       throw new Exception("Unepxected PEM type");
   }
   ```
3. After I have made change 1 and 2, I still have an error in Postman: "consent_required". Turns out I have to add a redirect uri to my integrator key then navigate to this url:

   ```
   SERVER/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=https://docusign.com
   ```

and click "Grant".

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you've correctly authorized the integration key from the org admin panel then you should not receive the consent_required error. Are you doing all of this in demo or on production? You need to use a demo org admin to grant consent within the demo environment.

Comment: @LarryK I'm doing all these in my demo environment and I have used a demo org admin to configure everything. Do you mean Change 3 in my answer is not necessary at all? If that's the case how do I get rid of consent_required error?

Comment: @ixsl Thank you very much for this. I spent a day and half banging my head against the wall trying to use .Net Core libraries, once I imported Nuget `Portable.BounyCastle v1.8.5.2` and followed your example code, I was able to get the access token. What a pain in the arse this was!!!